# Click element or Button on RobotFramework

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a problem to click an element/button using RobotFramework in a web page.

When I launch the script, an issue related to frame part is displayed.

I used the inspection code and I selected the element necessary to use the command 'Click element' or 'Click button'.

Here the code and the code where the element have to be clicked.

```html
<iframe class="calculator-frame" frameborder="0" height="900px" id="lease-calculator" scrolling="no" src="/sites/default/files/web/calc/Leasing/html/lease.html?eng" style="overflow: auto;" width="670px">
#document
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="lease">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lease Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../css/base.css" />
<script src="../js/vendor/bowser.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/vendor/moment-range.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/libs1418141549195.js"></script>
<script src="../js/calculator1418141549195.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="LeaseCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <div class="container"  style="position: relative;">    
        <div class="row">
            <form id="leaseForm" name="leaseForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                <div class="span6" style="margin-left: -4px"><!--First Column-->
                    <label class="control-label">
                        {{ 'type-of-lease' | i18n }}
                    </label>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            <label class="radio" style="font-weight: normal;">
                                <input id="operating" type="radio" ng-model="leaseType"
                                    value="operating" ng-change="canExecute = false"/>
                                {{ 'operating-lease' | i18n }}
                            </label>

                            <label class="radio" style="font-weight: normal;">
                                <input id="financial" type="radio" ng-model="leaseType" 
                                    value="financial" ng-change="canExecute = false"/>
                                {{ 'financial-lease' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="price">
                            {{ 'property-price' | i18n }}
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                                
                                <div class="input-append">
                                    <input id="price" name="price" ng-model="price.value" data-min="{{price.min}}"
                                        ng-change="priceChange()" class="input-small" type="text" required float/>
                                    <span class="add-on">{{ currency }}</span>
                                </div>
                            <p class="comment">{{ 'enter-price-with-vat' | i18n }}</p>

                            <span class="help-block error" 
                                ng-show="leaseForm.price.$error.float ||leaseForm.price.$error.min || leaseForm.price.$error.required">
                                {{ 'range-of' | i18n }} {{ price.min }}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contractFee">
                            {{ 'contract-fee' | i18n }}
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-append">
                                <input id="contractFee" name="contractFee" ng-model="contractFee.value"
                                    ng-change="contractFeeChanged()" class="input-small" type="text" required float/>
                                <span class="add-on">{{ currency }}</span>
                            </div>

                            <span id="contractFeeComment" class="comment nowrap">{{ contractFeeEquivalent | number }} {{ alternativeCurrency }}</span>
                            
                            <span class="help-block error" id="contractFeeError" ng-model="showContractFeeError"
                                ng-show="showContractFeeError">
                                {{ 'range-of' | i18n }} {{ contractFee.min |number }}
                            </span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="downpaymentType">
                            <span ng-show="leaseType == 'operating'">{{ 'downpayment' | i18n }}</span>
                            <span ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">{{ 'first-payment' | i18n }}</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            <input id="downpayment" name="downpayment" ng-model="downpayment.value"
                                data-min="{{downpayment.min}}" data-max="{{downpayment.max}}"ng-change="downpaymentChanged()"
                                    class="input-mini" type="text" required integer/>

                            <select ng-model="downpaymentType" id="downpaymentType" class="input-tinny" ng-change="downpaymentTypeChanged()">
                                <option value="%">%</option>
                                <option value="{{currency}}">{{currency}}</option>
                            </select><br />

                            <span ng-show="downpaymentType == '%'" id="downpaymentComment" class="comment">
                                {{ downpaymentMoney | number }} {{ currency }}
                            </span>
                    
                            <span class="help-block error" 
                                ng-show="((leaseForm.downpayment.$error.min || leaseForm.downpayment.$error.max) && downpaymentType == '%') ||
                                leaseForm.downpayment.$error.required || leaseForm.downpayment.$error.integer">
                                {{ 'range-of' | i18n }} {{ downpayment.min }} {{ 'range-to' | i18n }} {{ downpayment.max }}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contractPeriod">
                            {{ 'contract-period' | i18n }}
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select ng-model="contractPeriod" ng-options="period for period in periods" 
                                class="input-mini" id="contractPeriod">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="financialCol1" ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="propertyType">
                                {{ 'property-type' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select ng-model="propertyType" ng-change="propertyTypeChanged()"
                                    class="input-choose" id="propertyType" ng-required="leaseType == 'financial'">
                                    <option value="">{{ 'choose-one' | i18n }}</option>
                                    <option value="new">{{ 'new' | i18n }}</option>
                                    <option value="used">{{ 'used' | i18n }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /div .span6 First Column-->

                <div class="span"><!--Middle Column-->
                    <div class="column-separator"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="span6"><!--Second Column -->
                    <div id="operatingCol2a" ng-show="leaseType == 'operating'">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                {{ 'set-downpayment' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls controls-row">

                                <label class="radio" style="font-weight: normal;">
                                    <input type="radio" id="setDownpaymentYes" ng-change="setDownpayment = 'true'"
                                        ng-model="setDownpayment" value="true"/>
                                    {{ 'yes' | i18n }}
                                </label>

                                <label class="radio" style="font-weight: normal;">
                                    <input type="radio" id="setDownpaymentNo" ng-change="setDownpayment = 'false'"
                                        ng-model="setDownpayment" value="false"/>
                                    {{ 'no' | i18n }}
                                </label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="financialCol2a" ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="propertyYear">
                                {{ 'year' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select ng-model="propertyYear" ng-disabled="propertyType == '' || propertyType == 'new'"
                                    ng-options="year for year in yearsList" class="input-choose" id="propertyYear" ng-required="leaseType == 'financial'">
                                    <option value="">{{ 'choose-one' | i18n }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="carCategory">
                                {{ 'car-category' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select ng-model="carCategory" ng-change="modelsForBrand()" 
                                    ng-disabled="propertyYear == ''" id="carCategory" class="input-normal" ng-required="leaseType == 'financial'">
                                    <option value="">{{ 'choose-one' | i18n }}</option>
                                    <option value="passenger">{{ 'passenger-car' | i18n }}</option>
                                    <option value="truck">{{ 'truck-car' | i18n }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="carBrand">
                                {{ 'car-brand' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select id="carBrand" name="carBrand" ng-model="carBrand" ng-change="modelsForBrand()" ng-disabled="carCategory == ''"
                                    ng-options="brand for brand in carBrands" class="input-normal" ng-required="leaseType == 'financial'">
                                    <option value="">{{ 'choose-one' | i18n }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="carModel">
                                {{ 'car-model' | i18n }}
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select ng-model="carModel" ng-options="model for model in carModels"
                                    class="input-normal" id="carModel" ng-disabled="carBrand == ''" ng-required="leaseType == 'financial'">
                                    <option value="">{{ 'choose-one' | i18n }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="interestRate">
                            {{ 'interest-rate' | i18n }}
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            <div class="input-append">
                                <input id="interestRate" name="interestRate" ng-model="interestRate.value" data-min="{{interestRate.min}}"
                                    data-max="{{interestRate.max}}" class="input-small" type="text" required float/>
                                <span class="add-on">%</span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block error" 
                                ng-show="leaseForm.interestRate.$error.min || leaseForm.interestRate.$error.max ||
                                leaseForm.interestRate.$error.required || leaseForm.interestRate.$error.float">
                                {{ 'incorrect-interest-rate' | i18n }}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="operatingCol2b" ng-show="leaseType == 'operating'">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="residualValue">
                                {{ 'residual-value' | i18n }}    
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                <input id="residualValue" name="residualValue" ng-model="residualValue.value"
                                    data-min="{{residualValue.min}}" data-max="{{residualValue.max}}" 
                                    ng-required="leaseType == 'operating'" class="input-mini" type="text" required float/>
                                <select ng-model="residualValueType"
                                        ng-change="residualValueTypeChanged()" class="input-tinny">
                                    <option>%</option>
                                    <option>{{currency}}</option>
                                </select>

                                <span class="help-block"
                                    ng-show="leaseForm.residualValue.$error.float || leaseForm.residualValue.$error.min ||
                                    leaseForm.residualValue.$error.max || leaseForm.residualValue.$error.required">
                                  <span class="error">{{ 'range-of' | i18n }} {{  residualValue.min }}</span>
                                  <span class="error" ng-show="residualValueType == '%'">{{ 'range-to' | i18n }} {{ residualValue.max }}</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="monthlyPayment-operating">
                                {{ 'monthly-payment' | i18n }}
                            </label>

                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                <label id="monthlyPayment-operating" class="highlight-green">
                                    {{ operatingMonthlyPayment | number }} {{ currency }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="financialCol2b" ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="monthlyPayment-financial">
                                {{ 'monthly-payment' | i18n }}
                            </label>

                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                <label id="monthlyPayment-financial"  class="highlight-green">
                                    {{ financialMonthlyPayment | number }} {{ currency }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="aprHighlight">
                                {{ 'apr' | i18n }} 
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                <label id="aprHighlight" class="highlight-green">
                                    {{ financialAPR | number }}%
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group pull-right">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <a class="button big" id="getSchedule" ng-click="getSchedule(leaseType)">
                                <span>{{ 'calculate' | i18n }}</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div><!-- /div .span6 Second Column-->

            </form><!-- /form .form-horizontal -->
        </div><!-- /div .row -->
    </div><!-- /div .container -->

    <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="alertError" class="msg-error" ng-show="showErrorMessage">
                {{ 'msg-unable-to-issue-lease' | i18n }}
            </div>

            <div class="span12">
                <br />
                <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="'lease-calculator-msg' | i18n"></p>
                <p ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">{{ 'lease-calculator-insurance-msg' | i18n }}</p>
            </div>

            <div id="tables" class="span12" ng-show="canExecute && leaseType != 'operating'">
                <div class="hr-thick"><hr /></div>
                <h3>{{ 'payment-schedule' | i18n }}</h3>

                <div id="table-operating" ng-show="leaseType == 'operating'">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                        <th style="width: 10%">{{ 'month-no' | i18n }}</th>
                        <th style="width: 30%;">{{ 'uncovered-outstanding-value' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%;">{{ 'rent' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%;">{{ 'total' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%;">{{ 'collateral-type' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%;">{{ 'collateral' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                        <tr ng-repeat="payment in operatingSchedule">
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].no }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].leftToPay }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].rent  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].total }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].downpaymentInclusion }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingSchedule[$index].downpayment }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <td class="input-mini">{{ 'total' | i18n }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{{ operatingTotal.rent }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingTotal.total }}</td>
                            <td>{{ operatingTotal.downpaymentInclusion }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /div #table-operating -->

                <div id="table-financial" ng-show="leaseType == 'financial'">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                            <th style="width: 10%">{{ 'month-no' | i18n }}</th>
                            <th>{{ 'uncovered-outstanding-value' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>{{ 'value-coverage-amount' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>{{ 'interest-rate' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>{{ 'total' | i18n }} ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>If P&C Insurance AS ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>AB &#8222;Lietuvos draudimas&#8221; ({{ currency }})</th>
                            <th>&#8222;PZU Lietuva&#8221; ({{ currency }})</th>

                        <tr ng-repeat="payment in financialSchedule">
                            <td>{{ financialSchedule[$index].no }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialSchedule[$index].leftToPay  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialSchedule[$index].downpayment }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialSchedule[$index].interest }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialSchedule[$index].total }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.IF.schedule[$index] || '-' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.LD.schedule[$index] || '-' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.PZU.schedule[$index] || '-' }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <td class="input-mini">{{ 'total' | i18n }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{{ financialTotal.downpayment }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialTotal.interest }}</td>
                            <td>{{ financialTotal.total }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.IF.total }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.LD.total  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ insurance.PZU.total }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /div #table-financial -->

            </div><!-- /div #tables -->
        </div><!-- /div .row -->
    </div><!-- /div .container -->
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">BrowserDetect.checkSupport();</script>
</html>
</iframe>
```

The part that I am interested to execute is this:

```html
 <div class="control-group pull-right">
   <div class="controls">
     <a class="button big" id="getSchedule" ng-click="getSchedule(leaseType)">
      <span>{{ 'calculate' | i18n }}</span>
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I used this:

```html
User fill in the fields

[Documentation]                             The user can fill in all fields

OPEN BROWSER                                https://www.seb.lt/eng/private/calculator-leasing    chrome
wait until page contains                    Calculator of leasing
select frame                                ${frame}
input text                                  ${price}  500000
sleep                                       30s
click element                               ${calculate}
CLOSE BROWSER
```

I hope that I gave all information so that I can solve my issue.

Thanks
Angelo

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in firefox browser.

```
*** Settings ***

Library    Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***

${URL}            https://www.seb.lt/eng/private/calculator-leasing
${BROWSER}        firefox

*** Test Cases ***

User fill in the fields

    [Documentation]         The user can fill in all fields

    OPEN BROWSER                ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    wait until page contains    Calculator of leasing
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   css=iframe[id="lease-calculator"]   10
    Select Frame            css=iframe[id="lease-calculator"]
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   css=input[id="price"]           10
    input text              css=input[id="price"]           500000
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   css=a[id="getSchedule"]         10
    Click Element           css=a[id="getSchedule"]
```

It works for me.
use geckodriver 17 for firefox.

- In chrome browser may b you get some cookies related pop up than you need to close that in your script. but for firefox it works fine.

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you explained what you did to make the code work. Without the explanation, the reader must go through your code line by line, comparing it to the code in the question.

Comment: Yeah bryan i would try to remember if i answer any question in future.

Comment: Yes! It is working after I changed the browser. Thanks for your help!